# Save the for-loop index for certain values to be used later

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create two spreadsheets: one tracks student attendance at school, the other tracks their attendance at Track practice. The goal is to write a function, that I can set up as a button, that I can click that will automatically send emails to several people if the student is present at school but is absent for sports without getting excused.

Right now, the whole thing is working pretty well, but I have one issue. I have a column that will read "Good" or "Bad" depending on whether the student meets the above condition. The function turns these into an array. I would like to use the index of the "Bad"'s to find the necessary email addresses, which are stored at the same index point in another array that I make from the spreadsheet. I'm not sure how to save this index point and use it to reference the email addresses. Code below.

```
function sendEmailsMonday() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TrackAttendance");
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("D2:D30");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();// Gets array of "Good" and "Bad"
  for (i in data) {
    if(i = "Bad") {
      var place = data.indexOf(i);
      var dataRange2 = sheet.getRange("M2:M30");// Gets array of email addresses
      var data2 = dataRange2.getValues();
      var emailAddress = data2[place];
      var message = "This is an automated email informing you that your child/advisee ____ was present at school today, but missed Track without being excused. Feel free to email Mr. @ with any questions.";
      var subject = "___ missed Track Practice";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

So, the issue comes in with the index lines. If I get rid of

```
var place = data.indexOf(i);
```

and replace

```
var emailAddress = data[place];
```

with

```
var emailAddress = data[28];
```

or any other number, it will grab the email address and send it. But then it has nothing to do with the values in the other column.

Seems like this should be an easy fix but I'm bad at this.

Answer (score 0):

Very late responding now. I think you are almost there.

Your IF statement should read:

```
if(i == "Bad") {
```

And then replace 'place' with i:

```
var emailAddress = data2[i];
```

It should work as expected now.